# How to convert following query into codeigniter query

Tags: php, codeigniter

So This is the following query i want convert into codeigniter:

```
$q = "DELETE FROM  group_info, contacts

USING group_info INNER JOIN contacts 

WHERE group_info.gid = '$gid'

AND contacts.gid = group_info.gid";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't think you can achieve this with the `Query Builder` properly

Instead - i'd suggest the following

```
$this->db->query("DELETE FROM  group_info, contacts USING group_info INNER JOIN contacts WHERE group_info.gid = ? AND contacts.gid = group_info.gid", array($gid));
```

In this case you are protected via bindings

> You can find this exact information [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#query-bindings)

Comment: Thanks @sintakonte. I will try this one.

Comment: Sorry @sintakonte it is working fine now, i misunderstood it

Comment: Thank you so much !